# Batch file task does not complete all commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, winscp

I write a lot of DOS based batch files usually to collect files from clients FTP servers, move the file about to different folders on our server, decrypt files, unzip files etc.

I wrote a DOS batch file, which works perfectly when I run it from command line. So there isn't any issue there. I setup a Windows task on our Windows 2008 server. I copied all the conditions, triggers and configuration from a working task that we use for a different client. However the task that then runs on a schedule is saying it's ran correctly, however it hasn't completed all the commands in the batch file, it seems to be corrupting the zip file that it's downloading rather than unzipping it. But again if I run my batch file manually it works everytime.

Anyone got any thoughts?

Comment: While moving execution to a task you must check 1) what profile is used; 2) does the profile is loaded fully; 3) what is current drive and folder. So use `CMD /С batchfile.bat [parameters]`, use explicit drive/folder change, do not use relative paths. To debug execution use `CMD /K ...` and view all execution messages.

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)